# NodeJS + mongoDB query after another : Promises/callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await

I have three functions

A -> mongoDb query then call B then console.log("test")

B -> set some rules and call C

C --> mongoDb query go back to A -> console.log("test")

I am having a hard time with async/promises, after quite a long time I found a working solution that does not seem super elegant.
(Maybe because I'm not super familiar with async/await)
I was wondering if there's a better/more elegant/more readable solution?

Here's the code with only the "useful part". (The console.logs should write 1,2,3,4,5,6.)

````
app.get('/searchWingding', (req,res)=>{
    users.findOneAndUpdate( mongoDBQuery
                                    {returnOriginal : false})
                        .then(async () =>{  
                            //remove unnecessary code for issue
                                console.log(1)                                  
                                await wingdingsExhibitionRule(users,player, allWingdings)
                                console.log(6)
                            })})

async function wingdingsExhibitionRule(users,player, wingdingsList){
        //remove unnecessary code for issue
        console.log(2)                                  
    await changePlayerUnlock(users,player,"wingdingsExhibition")
    console.log(5)                                  
}

async function changePlayerUnlock(users,player,unlockRule){
    //remove unnecessary code for issue
    console.log(3)
const a = users.findOneAndUpdate(mongoDBQuery,
                        {returnOriginal : false})
.then(()=>{                 
                            console.log(4)
                            if(!checkStringInArray(player.unlock,unlockRule)){
                            player.unlock.push(unlockRule)
                            }
                        })
await a
}
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `async-await` syntax as well as promises. Your code can be written as shown below using only `async-await` syntax

```
app.get('/searchWingding', async (req,res)=> {
      await users.findOneAndUpdate()
      console.log(1)
      await wingdingsExhibitionRule(users,player, allWingdings)
      console.log(6)

async function wingdingsExhibitionRule(users,player, wingdingsList){
     console.log(2)                                  
     await changePlayerUnlock(users,player,"wingdingsExhibition")
     console.log(5)                                  
}

async function changePlayerUnlock(users,player,unlockRule) {
    console.log(3)
    const a = await users.findOneAndUpdate()
    console.log(4)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes way more sense !

Comment: I'm changing my overall code to remove all promises, it's so much clearer. Thanks a lot for your help!